# On Variation of Parameters - Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need guidance to complete this problem properly. I have

$$y'' - 7y' = -3$$

I am asked to find the general solution. To do that, I first start off by finding the characteristic polynomial

$$y_c = c_1e^{7x} + c_2$$

where $r=0, r=7$. A particular solution could perhaps resemble

$$y_p = u_1e^{7x} + u_2$$

where

$$u_1'e^{7x} + u_2' = 0$$ then
$$7u_1'e^{7x} = -3$$

Adding the two equations yeilds:

$$u_1'e^{7x}=u_2' => u_1'=-u_2'e^{-7x} = -3$$

Then I integrated to find $u_1, u_2$

$$u_1 = -\int{3dx} = 3x$$
$$u_2 = \int{e^{7x}} = \frac{1}{7}e^{7x}$$

So my particular solution, $y_p$ is

$$y_p = u_1e^{7x}+u_2 = -3xe^{7x} + \frac{1}{7}e^{7x}$$

I found the general solution as

$$y = c_1e^{7x} + c_2 - 3xe^{7x} + \frac{1}{7}e^{7x}$$

but that is incorrect. What is left undone? What have I done wrong? Is this the right methodology/technique to be using?

Comment: In the second equation you should not have a $u_2'$ the derivative of a constant is 0

Comment: I suggest that the particular solution is a polynomial.

Comment: Then it would be -$\frac{3}{7}e^{-7x}$

Comment: Why is your particular solution so complicated?  Surely $y_p=Cx$ works.

Comment: Note:  as with your [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362039/variation-of-parameters-differential-equations) you appear to overcomplicate the search for particular solutions.  I'd practice that.

Comment: @lulu $y''_p = 0$, $y'_p = C$. So, $c=-3$ and $y_p = -3x$ How do I proceed from there?

Comment: No...The differential operator on the left is $D[y]=y''-7y$.  Thus $D[Cx]=0-7\times C=-7C$.  Thus you want $-7C=-3$ or $C=\frac 37$.  You already have the homogeneous solution (well, I didn't check but it is straight forward).

Comment: Note:  letting $z=y'$ this is just the first order linear equation $z'-7z=-3$.  This can be solved by multiplying both  sides by $e^{-7x}$ and integrating.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @lulu $\int{e^{-7x}v'dx} -7 \int{e^{-7x}vdx} = -3\int{e^{-7x}dx}$

Comment: No...have you studied first order linear equations?  The goal is to produce an integrating factor.  Here, $e^{-7x}$ will work.  Multiplying both sides by that I get $\frac d{dx} \left(e^{-7x}z\right)=-3e^{-7x}$.   Now it is easy to integrate.  But if you have never studied ODE's before you should do some reading on the basics.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve this one would be to set $v=y'\implies v'=y''$ the equation becomes $v'-7v=-3$ which is separable.